# The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)

Tags: windows, windows-10, path

```
Windows 10 
OS Build 19043.1348
Ninja version 1.10.0.git
```

**Source Code Path:-**

```
C:\Users\runersystem\AppData\Local\.mabs\siml-mibs-mrunner-m99-w88\workspace\projects\develop\mizen-scri1\tmp-cache\
```

**Build command:** Executed from above path.

```
res/windows/ninja.exe -C build -f build.windows.ninja
```

**Error:-**

> cp: error:
> '../res/eemplates/wob/pearaele/Mommoe/MUALib/rel/eau/eemplates/theme/changeable/images/Colector/R_Potary_selector_edit_pold_ic_delete_rg.png'
> -> '../dist/eemplates/wob/pearaele/Mommoe/MUALib/rel/eau/eemplates/theme/changeable/images/Colector/R_Potary_selector_edit_pold_ic_delete_rg.png':
> The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)
>
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

`dist` directory create during run time and copies the files.

**Path:** - In the following path- No Errors. Copy and build works.

```
C:\Users\runersystem\AppData\Local\.mabs\siml-mibs-mrunner-m99-w88\workspace\projects\develop\mizen-scri1\test\
```

For Example, Like below if i create one extra character it fails with above errors.

```
C:\Users\runersystem\AppData\Local\.mabs\siml-mibs-mrunner-m99-w88\workspace\projects\develop\mizen-scri1\test1\
```

I'm not sure why with path length getting `The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)` error.

1. The account `runersystem` is local system user and member of `Administrator` and `Power users` groups.
2. Windows 10 to accept File Paths Over `260 Characters` enabled `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`  - `LongPathsEnabled` - `1`
3. Windows Update performed
4. Antivirus Un-installed.
5. Disk cleanup (Using Disk Cleanup) performed.
6. `chkdsk` scan performed.
7. `sfc /scannow` command executed.
8. User & System variables no issues.

Still encountering the same problem with length folder path. Also checked on another `Windows-10` system even in that also same problem persists.

Can someone let me know, what is wrong with directory length? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the _Event Viewer_ to check Windows Logs (Application and System). Perhaps you will find some addition useful information about what caused this error.

Comment: @Jackdaw, `No errors` in  `Event Viewer` - `Windows Logs (Application and System)`

Comment: Can you include the entire PATH, not only this one folder? Enter in CMD the command `path > file` and copy the contents into your post.

Comment: @harrymc, Entire PATH have already provided in question. In the given path only on GitBash i run `res/windows/ninja.exe -C build -f build.windows.ninja` build command.

Comment: GitBash combines its PATH with that of Windows. Try `env | grep PATH`.

Comment: It prints `EXEPATH`, `PATHEXT`, `ACLOCAL_PATH`, `MANPATH`, `PATH` values.

Comment: Same error occurs even on `Windows command prompt` as well.

Comment: Manually able to `copy`, But through `ninja` it shows above mentioned error.